# python matplotlib candlestick chart

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm having trouble creating a candlestick chart with intraday 15 minute bars. I download and parse the data from google and save it locally to a csv file. I parse the data and load it to a variable with the following order float date, open, high, low, close, volume. When I do it with historical daily data all is ok, but when I try to do it with a date and time x axis it messes up. Here is the sample data which I use:

> 2015-10-05 16:30:00,196.47,196.48,196.43,196.46,438838,0 2015-10-05
>   16:45:00,196.46,197.08,196.33,196.95,2835287,0 2015-10-05
>   17:00:00,196.95,197.38,196.92,197.32,1732829,0 2015-10-05
>   17:15:00,197.32,197.53,196.95,197.44,1988081,0 2015-10-05
>   17:30:00,197.46,197.59,197.29,197.42,1226381,0 2015-10-05
>   17:45:00,197.425,197.48,196.9,196.93,1101573,0 2015-10-05
>   18:00:00,196.93,197.23,196.84,197.15,646694,0 2015-10-05
>   18:15:00,197.16,197.51,197.11,197.45,623662,0 2015-10-05
>   18:30:00,197.45,197.46,197.18,197.26,684113,0 2015-10-05
>   18:45:00,197.255,197.42,197.1,197.14,764368,0 2015-10-05
>   19:00:00,197.14,197.48,197.13,197.46,476307,0 2015-10-05
>   19:15:00,197.46,197.67,197.4,197.54,758593,0 2015-10-05
>   19:30:00,197.55,197.77,197.44,197.58,929402,0 2015-10-05
>   19:45:00,197.605,197.73,197.565,197.71,493741,0 2015-10-05
>   20:00:00,197.73,197.84,197.5,197.6,542889,0 2015-10-05
>   20:15:00,197.61,197.91,197.49,197.84,535851,0 2015-10-05
>   20:30:00,197.85,198.08,197.85,197.95,629089,0 2015-10-05
>   20:45:00,197.95,198.03,197.84,197.9,465000,0 2015-10-05
>   21:00:00,197.895,198.16,197.895,198.08,658012,0 2015-10-05
>   21:15:00,198.095,198.2,197.98,198.11,643964,0 2015-10-05
>   21:30:00,198.115,198.48,198.09,198.47,1311870,0 2015-10-05
>   21:45:00,198.47,198.68,198.47,198.54,1414104,0 2015-10-05
>   22:00:00,198.53,198.54,198.31,198.43,885886,0 2015-10-05
>   22:15:00,198.43,198.68,198.36,198.46,1541751,0 2015-10-05
>   22:30:00,198.465,198.51,198.275,198.44,861833,0 2015-10-05
>   22:45:00,198.44,198.74,198.295,198.32,1847980,0 2015-10-05
>   23:00:00,198.31,198.65,198.31,198.46,2884656,0

Here is the code that parses the file and returns the prepared arrays for creating the chart:

```
def get_local_intraday_db(self, symbol, seconds_period, period = (None, None)):
    data = None

    if os.path.isfile(FILE_GENERATOR_INTRADAY.format(DB_PATH, symbol, seconds_period)):
        saved_data = open(FILE_GENERATOR_INTRADAY.format(DB_PATH, symbol, seconds_period), 'r')
        data = saved_data.read().split('\n')

        ohlcv_data = []
        date_data = []
        open_data = []
        high_data = []
        low_data = []
        close_data = []
        volume_data = []

        for line in data:
            splitted_line = line.split(',')

            datetime_to_float = mdates.date2num(datetime.datetime.strptime(splitted_line[0], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
            date_data.append(datetime_to_float)

            open_to_float = float(splitted_line[1])
            open_data.append(open_to_float)

            high_to_float = float(splitted_line[2])
            high_data.append(high_to_float)

            low_to_float = float(splitted_line[3])
            low_data.append(low_to_float)

            close_to_float = float(splitted_line[4])
            close_data.append(close_to_float)

            volume_to_float = float(splitted_line[5])
            volume_data.append(volume_to_float)

            ohlcv_data.append((datetime_to_float, open_to_float, high_to_float, low_to_float, close_to_float, volume_to_float))

        if period == (None, None):
            return ( ohlcv_data, np.array(date_data), np.array(open_data), np.array(high_data), np.array(low_data), np.array(close_data), np.array(volume_data) )
        else:
            try:
                range_start = mdates.date2num(period[0])
                range_start_index = date_data.index(range_start)
                range_end = mdates.date2num(period[1])
                range_end_index = date_data.index(range_end)

                if range_start_index >= 0 and range_end_index >= 0:
                    print '{}: Selected range starts from {} to {}.'.format(datetime.datetime.now(), period[0], period[1])
                    return ( ohlcv_data[range_start_index : range_end_index], np.array(date_data[range_start_index : range_end_index]), np.array(open_data[range_start_index : range_end_index]), np.array(high_data[range_start_index : range_end_index]), np.array(low_data[range_start_index : range_end_index]), np.array(close_data[range_start_index : range_end_index]), np.array(volume_data[range_start_index : range_end_index]) )
                else:
                    print '{}: Selected data range is invalid!'.format(datetime.datetime.now())
            except:
                print 'No source provider data for {}.'.format(symbol)
                return ( None, None, None, None, None, None, None )
    else:
        print '{}: No data exists for {}!'.format(datetime.datetime.now(), symbol)
```

And here is the code that creates the chart:

```
def create_chart_intraday(self, symbol, ohlcv_data, date_data, open_data, high_data, low_data, close_data, volume_data):
    if ohlcv_data == None:
        return
    _start = datetime.datetime.now()       
    fig = plt.figure(facecolor = 'white')
    fig.set_size_inches(18., 10.)
    fig.text(0.5, 0.75, symbol, fontsize = 40, color = 'black', ha = 'center', va = 'center', alpha = 0.1)

    xmin = date_data[0]
    xmax = date_data[len(date_data) - 1]
    #Candlestick chart
    ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((12, 6), (0, 0), rowspan = 6, colspan = 6, axisbg = 'white')
    ax1.grid(True, color = 'black')
    ax1.axes.xaxis.set_ticklabels([])
    ax1.axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
    ax1.xaxis.set_major_locator(mticker.MaxNLocator(10))
    ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
    ax1.yaxis.label.set_color('black')
    ax1.spines['bottom'].set_color('black')
    ax1.spines['top'].set_color('black')
    ax1.spines['left'].set_color('black')
    ax1.spines['right'].set_color('black')
    ax1.tick_params(axis = 'y', colors = 'black')
    ax1.set_xlim(xmin, xmax)

    plt.ylabel('Price & Volume')
    candlestick_ohlc(ax1, ohlcv_data, colorup = 'purple', colordown = 'red')        
    ax1.plot(date_data, open_data, 'blue', linewidth = 0.5)
    ax1.plot(date_data, high_data, 'green', linewidth = 0.5)
    ax1.plot(date_data, low_data, 'red', linewidth = 0.5)
    ax1.plot(date_data, close_data, 'yellow', linewidth = 0.5)
    plt.show()

    _end = datetime.datetime.now()
    print 'Chart generated in {}'.format(str(_end - _start))

    fig.savefig('{}{}.png'.format(PNG_PATH, symbol), facecolor = fig.get_facecolor())
```

[image]

You can see that there is a problem. I have made for lines that mark the open, high, low, close, but the body fill of the candles is not where it has to be. The purple/red colors should fill the bodies of the candles but actually they are somewhere else. Can somebody help me fix that? Thanks in advance

Comment: First of all, is that really your sample data? Perhaps the date should be always first in each line? (right now see how it is appended at the end of each line, but the last one).

Comment: @Peque, I copied the data given in the question, formatted it, and it worked fine, but when I tried posting the right data into my answer, it was automatically changed to exactly what was in the question, so probably OP uses the right data.

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote your code in python3 and it probably works as it should, though I can't tell what exactly fixed the problem. My guess is - the new data extraction function, but I can't tell for sure. Here is my code (should also work in python2):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.finance import *
import datetime

def get_data_simple():
    ohlcv_data = []

    data = open('test1') # Path to file with sample data

    for line in data:
        splitted_line = line.split(',')

        ohlcv = [(datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.datetime.strptime(splitted_line[0], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')).total_seconds()]

        for elem in splitted_line[1:]:
            ohlcv.append(float(elem))

        ohlcv_data.append(ohlcv)

    return ohlcv_data

def create_chart_intraday(ohlcv_data):
    ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((12, 6), (0, 0), rowspan = 6, colspan = 6, axisbg = 'white')
    candlestick_ohlc(ax1, ohlcv_data, colorup = 'purple', colordown = 'red')
    plt.show()

create_chart_intraday(get_data_simple())
```

There are no titles or additional plots, but it works.
[image: My result]